# How to remove 0xa0 in Neo4j csv data?

Tags: neo4j

I have tried

```
replace(row.field, '0xa0', '')
```

which didn't work, it still insert whatever presented in the .csv file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

\xa0 is actually non-breaking space in Latin1 (ISO 8859-1), also chr(160). You should replace it with a space.

```
 replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
```

Let me know if it works and give me a sample csv file to trst it out.